# FindByLocationWithin(Circle x) retorna vacio CouchBase Spring

Tags: spring, couchbase

Intente hacer una consulta de vistas espaciales en `Spring` usando el repositorio de `CouchBase` ... donde coloco esto:

```
@Dimensional(designDocument = "paradas", spatialViewName = "paradas", dimensions = 2)
List<Parada> findByCoordenadaWithin(Circle x);
```

El problema es que si el parámetro es un `Box`, funciona, pero con`circle` devuelve una lista vacía...
Estoy casi seguro de que el problema está en el `Spring` al calcular los falsos positivos... esto lo sé porque en `aplication.Properties` incluí la depuración...

```
#Para logs de los querys
logging.level.org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

y el resulta de la consulta es...

```
2018-08-16 15:44:38.114 DEBUG 6480 --- [nio-8084-exec-2] o.s.d.c.r.query.SpatialViewBasedQuery    : Executing spatial view query: stale=false&start_range=[-9.2274133,-87.91111661]&end_range=[4.7725867,-73.91111661]
```

Si ejecuto esto en couchbase con la vista espacial funciona y devuelvo los documentos... Pero de alguna manera `Spring` no procesa los resultados... En la segunda linea se observa el arreglo.

```
2018-08-16 15:49:05.068 DEBUG 3828 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.s.d.c.r.query.SpatialViewBasedQuery    : Executing spatial view query: stale=false&start_range=[-9.2274133,-87.91111661]&end_range=[4.7725867,-73.91111661]
2018-08-16 15:49:05.197 DEBUG 3828 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [[]] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1debc91c]
2018-08-16 15:49:05.197 DEBUG 3828 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-16 15:49:05.197 DEBUG 3828 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

CABE RECALCAR QUE ESTOY USANDO SPRING BOOT 1.5.10.RELEASE Y COUCHBASE 5.0

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Lo siento, como pensé que la mayoría de info sobre spring y couchbase esta en Ingles, pero no pensé que influía en cambio de idioma. Pero gracias por la corrección. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Pude resolver mi Problema, la cual radicaba en el tipo de dato donde se almacenaba la coordenada, debía ser importado de:

```
org.springframework.data.geo.Point
```

Comment: Buena solución. Funciono, muchas gracias.